# How to alert the data-id attribute value in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

**Ajax1:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.CategoryName').click(function() {
        var categoryName = $(this).attr("data-id"); 
        var url="{{url('getSubCategoryName/').'/'}}" + categoryName;
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
                $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                    var output = '';
                    output = ' ' + value.subCategoryName + '';
                    **$(".subcategory").append('<ul><li data-
                    id="'+value.subCategoryName+'" class="getDeviceCategoryName">'+value.subCategoryName+'</li></ul>')**
                });
            }
        });
    });
});  
</script>
```

The code which is marked in bold has the value for data-id attribute..And I need to pass that value when class named `getDeviceCategoryName` is clicked.

**AJAX2:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.getDeviceCategoryName').click(function() {
        var subCategoryName = $(this).attr("data-id"); 
        alert(subCategoryName); 
    });
});  
</script>
```

This is one I tried for that..But its not working.It doesnot alerts or shows any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider jquery event delegation:
Change your jquery selector line like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click','.getDeviceCategoryName',function() {
        var subCategoryName = $(this).attr("data-id"); 
        alert(subCategoryName); 
    });
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Your welcome. Happy to help. Can you please accept my answer? And give it an Up vote?

Comment: @nishanthi, when there is any element which is created dynamically using ajax, httpx or angularjs $http request, the DOM would not be aware about the newly appended code snippet. So it can not execute jquery on the elements for which DOM is not aware as it was created after the page rendered.
In such case, we have to change the syntax a little, its called jquery event delegation. It means, it binds our jquery events, like `click` in your case, to the new element. Notice what I have changed in my answer.

Comment: understood..It really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.getDeviceCategoryName', function(){
        var subCategoryName = $(this).attr("data-id"); 
        alert(subCategoryName); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', 'li.getDeviceCategoryName', function() {
    console.log($(this).data("id")); 
  });
});
```

Since the elements are generated dynamically, so you need to `delegate events`.

For receiving the data-attribute you can do `$(this).data("attribute-name");` in your scenario it will be `$(this).data('id');`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think code is more efficient if the click event is applied to the element right after it's created.

```
$(function () {
  $('.CategoryName').click(function () {
    var categoryName = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = '{{url(\'getSubCategoryName/\').\'/\'}}' + categoryName;
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
          var output = '';
          output = ' ' + value.subCategoryName + '';
          $('.subcategory').append($('<ul/>').append('<li data-id="' + value.subCategoryName + '" class="getDeviceCategoryName">' + value.subCategoryName + '</li>')
                                   .find('li')
                                   .click(function () {
                                    var subCategoryName = $(this).attr('data-id');
                                    alert(subCategoryName);
          });
          );
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```